# Deep Copy of Struct Member Arrays

Tags: c++, c, arrays, struct, deep-copy

I have found this behaviour just right now, in the recent gcc.

Is such deep copying guaranteed behaviour by the C/C++ standard so okay to rely upon?

[edit] And what is the logic behind such behaviour? C array objects when copied with the `=` operator or as a function argument will always be regarded as a plain pointer. What is different about struct members?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct
{
    int arr[5];
}
array;

int main(void)
{
    array a = {{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}};
    array b;
    int i;

    b = a;
    b.arr[0] = 0;
    b.arr[1] = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        printf("%d %d\n", a.arr[i], b.arr[i]);
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

will output,

```
1 0
2 0
3 3
4 4
5 5
```

Comment: Yes, it is guaranteed. It isn't "deep" copying It is just "copying".

Comment: You should not ask a question about two different languages, there should be two different questions if you care about both.

Comment: @Vality Will the answer be different if this _specific_ question was asked for only one of either language?

Comment: @xiver77 Given you want to know if it is guaranteed by standard, yes. As a correct answer should explain where and how in the standard this is specified. This could not be done if you are not specifying which standard or even language the question is based on.

Comment: C and C++ don't have "deep copy" and "shallow copy" specifically. Instead they have *member-wise copy*. You could call this "shallow" if the member is a pointer or resource handle, and "deep" if the member is an array or a resource handler which has a copy-constructor that duplicates the resource.  Doesn't seem like useful terminology to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is indeed guaranteed behaviour. An array is **not** a pointer. An array is a contiguous sequence of elements, and its value is the value of all of its elements. So copying the array must mean copying all of its elements.

You're saying C objects copied with `=` or as function arguments are always treated as a pointer. That's not quite correct - C (and C++) arrays cannot be copied by `=`. And functions cannot have parameters (or return types) of array type - these are always adjusted to pointer type. And function arguments of array type undergo array-to-pointer conversion to match.

So the basic rule is: arrays are copied by value. The exception part is that functions cannot have parameters (and return values) of array type, pointers are silently used instead.

Comment: Arrays can't be copied by value, but what happens is that the same copying rules are applied recursively to members. So what ends up happening is `b.arr[0] = a.arr[0]; b.arr[1] = a.arr[1]; ` etc.